# How to pass php-script to Apache via Nginx using "location = script" directive?

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I have Nginx + Apache + PHP (as a module) installation at my server.

I need to restrict access to the only script at my site, say, `script.php` using
allow/deny direcitves in Nginx like this:

```
location / {
/* proxy settings */
}

location = /script.php {
allow 192.168.20.0/24;
deny all;
}
```

It works but the script is downloaded instead of execution if invoked in browser.

I think this happens because direct location (with "=" modificator) is selected first if matched and this request is not therefore passed to the Apache backend.

My question is how to execute a script specified in exact location directive?

Comment: You need to repeat your proxy settings in both locations.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, Richard, and did so.
Now I'm getting redirect to index.php though.

Comment: Problem was in trailing slash in the argument of proxy_pass directive. 
It is default in Openserver I'm using for now:
`proxy_pass                http://%ips%:%httpbackport%/;`
When removed Nginx follow the uri specified in location.